# How to Connect php and android to retrieve all data in a database table

Tags: php, android

How to Retrieve all data (all columns) inside database table to android

any helpful link or any youtube video this is php code I wanna retrieve all data inside (member) table using Android I wanna android COde thanks for any help and any guide..

```
$your_querry="select * from androidlogin ";
    $query=mysql_query($your_querry);
    $list=array();
              while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
              {
                  $list[]=$row;
              }

    echo json_encode($list);
```

Comment: Downvote because of no search efforts shown, This will help you, http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Comment: why DownVote ? this link I used already but I had a problem about using makeHttpRequest id undefined OK how to solve this help for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say the database has columns CITY_ID, CITY_NAME etc. Use the following

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView tv;
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   StrictMode.enableDefaults();  
    tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
    getData();
}
public void getData(){
 String result= "";
InputStream isr= null;
try{
HttpClient httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost= new HttpPost("http://your_ip_address/php_filename.php");// your ip address  and php file name here 
HttpResponse response=httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity entity= response.getEntity();
isr=entity.getContent();

}
 catch(Exception e){
     Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
     tv.setText("Couldnt connect to database");
 }
//convert response to string

try{
     BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isr,"iso-8859-1"),8);
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     String line = null;
     while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
             sb.append(line + "\n");
     }
     isr.close();

     result=sb.toString();
 }
 catch(Exception e){
     Log.e("log_tag", "Error  converting result "+e.toString());
}

 //parse json data
try {
   String s = "";
   JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

   for(int i=0; i<jArray.length();i++){
       JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
       s = s + 
               "ID : "+json.getString("CITY_ID") +"\n"+

               "NAME : "+json.getString("CITY_NAME")+"\n\n";
   }

   tv.setText(s);

} catch (Exception e) {
// TODO: handle exception
   Log.e("log_tag", "Error Parsing Data "+e.toString());
}

}

}
```

Also make sure to put the server online!

Comment: SOOoooooooooooooooooo awesome Thanks I appreciate
sorry I have no reputation thanks alot thankssss